# Why is App_Offline failing to work as soon as you it starts loading dlls?

Tags: asp.net, iis, app-offline.htm

Could anyone please help me with this. On the production site app_offline.htm works only till you start uploading dlls. As soon as you start uploading dlls it throws following error"Could not load file or assembly 'SubSonic' or one of its dependencies. 
**The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.**
Now this clearly shows that IIS is still trying to serve the aspx page?? Is there anything I am missing here?? Any help would be appreciated. I have spent hours googling but to no avail.
Thanks in advance.
Manisha

Comment: what version of .NET and IIS are you running? If it is in IIS 7 what App Pool style are you running?

Comment: I have this same problem. IIS 6, .net 2.0 and 3.5. I have worked around it by having the proxy serve the app_offline.htm when the w3svc is down.

Comment: For me this behavior still occurs on IIS 10 / ASP.NET 4.6 / Windows 2016

Answer (score 5):

I have heard of people having problems with app_offline.htm if it did not have enough content in the file.

Fill it with a couple hundred kb's of Lorem Ipsum text and see if that helps.

Comment: It needs to have 512 bytes (see http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/09/442332.aspx). Still erroring...

Answer (score 0):

Ok this might not be your problem, but if it's the first time it happened you might want to restart your machine. Sometimes a process dies with a lock on a .dll, thus you can no longer use it until unlocked (thus need a restart of the OS).

The other possible problem is that the .dll, or its dependent .dll's, aren't in your path or the correct folder.

Give both of these a look first.

Comment: if locking the dlls is the problem, set them to shadow copy

Comment: Good idea, hadn't thought about that myself.

Comment: I have this same problem, and I have shadow copying and the folders are OK.