# Problems with "app_offline.html" and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is App_Offline failing to work as soon as you it starts loading dlls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373540/why-is-app-offline-failing-to-work-as-soon-as-you-it-starts-loading-dlls)

Every time I had to update my ASP.NET application, I used to rename the file "app_offile.html" and the application would go offline. It still works with ASP.NET MVC, but when I start to upload the new versions and I refresh my browser, it gives me many errors because the application is being updated... so the "app_offline.html" is not working anymore.

Do you know what I should do?

I don't want my visitors to visit my website and get an error message. This is why this file exists.

ps: the file is bigger than 1k.

Cheers,
G

Comment: what error(s) are you getting?

Comment: app_offile.html won't work ;)

Comment: I never got this to work in MVC; I built my own process for sending the application offline.

Comment: @Brian What did you do? Could you explain your process?

Comment: actually it's **app_offline.htm** (notice it doesn't end with 'l') but I guess the OP already knows that.

Comment: @Guillermo A custom action invoker is the key; I used the view engine to check for the existence of an app_offline view, something like that.  When it exists, the user gets directed there.  I'd have to refresh on what I did exactly... don't have that code handy.